# Hibernate : SetMaxResults not working with java.util.Map

Tags: java, hibernate, hashmap

I am using Hibernate 3.0. Following is the criteria written for fetching data.

```
1. Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Document.class);
2. criteria.setMaxResults(10);
3. criteria.setFetchMode("metadata",FetchMode.join);
4. criteria.setFetchMode("activitySchedules", FetchMode.JOIN);
5. criteria.setFetchMode("activitySchedules.activities",FetchMode.JOIN); 
6. criteria.setResultTransformer(criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_PROPERTY);
7. criteria.list();
```

In this criteria, **setMaxResults(10)** is not working. It is giving only 1 result for defined 10 limit. For 20 it is giving 2 and likewise.If I comment 4th line, the result is coming in proper manner. I am not getting this weird behavior. Is it the problem with fetching MAP ? If anybody knows about this let me know.

**BeanStrucutre :**

**Document.java**

```
private NormMaster metadata;

private Map<TransactionFlowEnum, ActivitySchedule> activitySchedules;

 public NormMaster getMetadata(){
         return metadata;
}

public void setMetadata(NormMaster metadata){
   this.metadata = metadata;
}

public Map<TransactionFlowEnum, ActivitySchedule> getActivitySchedules() {
        return activitySchedules;
    }

 public void setActivitySchedules(
        Map<TransactionFlowEnum, ActivitySchedule> activitySchedules) {
        this.activitySchedules = activitySchedules;
    }
```

**ActivitySchedule.java**

```
private List<Stage> activities;

public List<Stage> getActivities() {
    return activities;
}

public void setActivities(List<Stage> activities) {
    this.activities = activities;
}
```

**NormMaster.java**

```
private String name;

public void setName(String name){
 this.name = name;
}

public return getName(){
 return name;
}
```

**Edit :** If I am putting one more field in Document.java and fetching metadata excluding activitySchedules then the proper data is coming.

Comment: Just a guess, `setMaxResults` is working on criteria and as you have also applied `DISTINCT_ROOT_PROPERTY`. It is actually producing 10 rows but as Distinct only one row get returned same is repeating when `setMaxResults(20)` this time it found 20 rows but only two are distinct. When you comment join operation it fetch 10 distinct rows and return them, I think `FetchMode.JOIN` is applying `inner join` try to perform a left join here, hope you will get the expected results.

Comment: @ manurajhada , There is no relation between setMaxResults and Distrinct_Root_Property. Distinct_Root is generally applied when we have applied FETCH_MODE join. If there are multiple joins at a time, hibernate returns multiple objects for that and when you apply Distinct_root it only gives 1 at a time with all joins.Sorry , but this is not the solution of my question.

Comment: As JB said, it applies on number of sql rows returns not on the objects, it means your join is returning number of sql rows but only one object as per the condition.

Comment: @ manurajhada , @ JB : Please go through the edits.

Comment: Have you actually read my answer? It explains why it works without the fetch join of the toMany association, and why it doesn't work with the fetch join of the toMany association.

Comment: Yeah JB , I go through each line that you wrote. But I am not able to understand why it is working with Fetching "metadata.?Eventhough if there would be List<NormMaster> it will work.But why not with ActivitySchedule.Correct me if I am getting wrong.And also provide the way to resolve. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setMaxResults()` limits the number of rows returned from the JDBC resultset coming from the SQL query executed. It doesn't limit the number of objects returned from the Criteria query.

For a simple request without any join fetch, the two numbers are the same. But for a query with a join fetch on a toMany association, the numbers aren't. For example, if a document has 2 schedules, and each of these schedules has 3 activites, your query will return 6 JDBC rows for this single document. So if you call `setMaxResults(4)`, you'll get onlmy one, incomplete, document from your query.

`setMaxResults()` should not be used with such queries. A workaround consists in executing a query returning only the IDs of the documents, and apply `setMaxResults()` on this query. Once you have the 10 IDs, you execute a second query, with the fetch joins, returning the documents having one of these 10 IDs (`where document.id in (:documentIds)`).